# How to find every active SVN repo on linux server

Tags: linux, svn

Is there any easy way to find the path of every Directory that is the root of an active SVN repo on a RHEL server?  I figure I could do a find for revprops or a directory named hooks or something.  Is there a more elegant method?  This would include both SVN protocol and websvn (http).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "active"?  You could do something like this to find all Subversion repositories that have seen activity in the past week:

```
find / -path '*/db/current' -mtime -7 -printf '%h\n'
```

Which would get you a list like:

```
/srv/svn/myrepo/db
/home/lars/projects/anotherrepo/db
```

If you strip off the `/db`, you have the list of repositories.

This command could take a long time to run depending on the size of the filesystems mounted on your system.

How the repository is accessed isn't particularly relevant here; the repository is the same regardless of whether it is accessed via `http`, `ssh`, `file`, etc.